# In Javascript, Value not comming instead the variable name is displayed

Tags: javascript

```
function ProvideValue(){

    Values = document.getElementById('HiddenValue').value;

FirstCut = Values.split("@#@"); // This will return the array ID@-@VALUE@-@TYPE

    var CtrlId;
    for (i = 0; i < FirstCut.length - 1; i++) {

        Strings = FirstCut[i];
        SecondCut = Strings.split("@-@");

        if(SecondCut[2].match("TEXT")) {
            CtrlId = "" + SecondCut[0];
            document.getElementById(CtrlId).value = SecondCut[1];
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code instead of the Id, which i can print it.But CtrlId is not replaced by the actual value. Am getting error  `document.getElementById(CtrlId).value is NULL`. I tried to hard code the ID then its working fine but i cannot hard code the controlsID because there are 1000s of control and everytime the ID changes.

Comment: Did you check that an element with a particular `CtrlId` actually exists in your document? I suspect there's no element with such ID. Use Firebug to analyse your HTML and debug your script so see what's going on.

Comment: You can also provide a JSFiddle with your problem so we can address your specific problem...

Comment: You're seriously in need of some `var`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your code seems fine** (apart from implied globals<sup>1</sup>), you must have some other problem in your HTML document... I'm also not sure why you're leaving out the last value from the *first cut* since you're interating to `length - 2`, because `i` is **less than** `length - 1` (not **less than or equal**) which means that it goes all the way to value `length - 2` and then breaks the loop.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FctrK/) I created that uses your code and displays some additional console messages and actually applies values to inputs as provided by the hidden input.

### <sup>1</sup>Important

I applied `var` to your variables so they're not *implied globals* which should be avoided at all times because they're nothing but evil friend of hidden bugs.

### The code I used

HTML is super simple but I do have both elements with IDs that are being addressed in the compound value of the hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="me@-@Rob@-@text@#@you@-@Mike@-@text" />
<input id="me" value="name" />
<input id="you" value="name" />​
```

Script is simple as well (runs on DOM ready for JSFiddle simplicity reasons):

```
var vals = document.getElementById('hidden').value;

var firstCut = vals.split("@#@");

for(var i = 0; i < firstCut.length; i++) {

    var ctrl = firstCut[i].split("@-@");

    if (ctrl[2].match("text")) {
      var id = ctrl[0];
      document.getElementById(id).value = ctrl[1];
    }
}​
```

Comment: I got it. the mistake was The first 2 controls was hidden fields coming from another page and that control was not in the display page. So it was throwing error. 

Thanks to everyone who helped me understand better. 
Happy Coding Guys...

Comment: @MikeRichard: Accepting an answer helps reward our time and effort helping you... Just sayin' :)

Comment: Sorry man just forgot to do that thanks again for reminding. :D

Comment: @MikeRichard: Nobody can blame you, you're new to SO community... :)